# UITableViewCell resizing automatically when presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a strange problem.

When my UITableView is presented, for a brief second, the cells change their height(not much but its noticeable and i do not like it). And it only changes when the device is running IOS 8. I tried it on my device using IOS 7 and nothing happened. Anyone knows what this can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a discrepancy between the UITableViewCell height in your xib/storyboard and the height you're specifying in the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Edit:

If that isn't your issue, try calling that delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    return 60; 
}
```

or:

Specifying a height that is not 'default' since the resizing probably has something to do with the scaling of device size.

Comment: i am not calling that delegate method, and in my storyboard the height is set to default

Comment: You can also specify a custom height for each single cell or prototype cell, are you doing that by any chance?

Comment: I'd suggest either 1) calling that delegate method (it's 3 lines of code):
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60;
}

or 

2) Specifying a height that is not 'default' since the resizing probably has something to do with the scaling of device size.

Comment: change your answer to your latest comment @kwdev it worked. I just set it to return 44 since its the default value. Thnx